# Make floating div 100% height of parent that uses min-height, while still allowing parent to expand

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a list of items where each item in the list contains essentially two columns ... the left column some text, and the right column 2 buttons for yes/no.  I want the two buttons on the right to be vertically aligned with the text.  For aesthetic reasons, I want a min-height on the list item.  I finally figured out that a floating div must be inside an absolute div for the 100% height to work.  The problem is now that I have an absolute div inside my original relative div, it no longer expands to accommodate text longer than min-height.  I've read so many articles and tried so many different combinations of height/relative/absolute/float/clear/overflow and nothing has worked for my situation.  Is there a solution to this?

In my example here http://jsfiddle.net/THBFY/4/ I need the red box to be the same height as the blue box so that the vertical align works.

```
<div class="list_container">
  <div class="list_item">
    <div class="item_text">
        My text in this item.  This could be a variable length creating a div ranging from about 75-150px in height.  This is a lot of text to make it longer although I am not really saying anything here.  It is only to make the blue box taller than the red box.
    </div>
    <div class="item_buttons">
      <div class="buttons_inner">
        <div class="button button_yes">Y</div>
        <div class="button button_no">N</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.list_container { position: relative; width: 400px; }
.list_item { position: relative; min-height: 70px; overflow: hidden; border: #000000 solid 1px; }
.item_text { float: left; width: 340px; background-color: #0066BB }
.item_buttons { display: table; float: right; width: 50px; height: 100%; background: #FF0000; }
.buttons_inner { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
.button { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 40px; width: 40px; background-repeat: no-repeat; }
.button_yes { background-image: url("images/yes.gif") }
.button_no { background-image: url("images/no.gif") }
```

When I add in the inner div with position:absolute http://jsfiddle.net/THBFY/5/ the problem is the height no longer increases to show all of the text.

```
<div class="list_item_inner">...
.list_item_inner { position: absolute; height: 100%; }
```

But if I now change the min-height of the outer div from 70 to 200 http://jsfiddle.net/THBFY/6/, you can see that the 100% height on the red box is in fact working, so my problem is either in the first situation without the absolute position, I need the red box to stretch, or in the 2nd situation with the absolute div, I need the container to stretch.

Comment: either use js or flexbox models which is part of html5

Comment: I would like to see an answer to the question title ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="list_container">
  <div class="list_item">
    <div class="item_text">My text in this item.  This could be a variable length creating a div ranging from about 75-150px in height.  This is a lot of text to make it longer although I am not really saying anything here.  It is only to make the blue box taller than the red box.
    </div>
    <div class="item_buttons">
      <div class="buttons_inner">
        <div class="button button_yes">Y</div>
        <div class="button button_no">N</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.list_container { position: relative; width: 400px; }

.list_item {  border: #000000 solid 1px; display:table; }

.item_text { display:table-cell; width: 340px; background-color: #0066BB }

.item_buttons { display:table-cell; width: 50px; background: #FF0000; }

.button { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; height: 40px; width: 40px; background-repeat: no-repeat; }

.button_yes { background-image: url("images/yes.gif"); }
.button_no { background-image: url("images/no.gif"); }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/THBFY/12/)

Comment: Thanks, that idea worked, with just a few other tweaks to really get it to do what I needed: list_item needs height set (note min-height does not work when display is table); added vertical-align:middle to item_buttons; also the div with buttons_inner is no longer necessary in the html.

Comment: @Inukshuk If this resolved your need then mark it accepted, else made your changes and update the question. Thanks :)